# In IE11, what date formats can be specified in the expires = <DATE> field of the set-Cookie header?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, setcookie

I'm using **internet explorer 11** with windows 10.

As a way to expire cookies, I have set the 'expires=' to a point in the past.

When I tested

The following formats are not supported. (Cookie was not removed.)

```
Set-Cookie: expires=Wed, 01-Jan-70 00:00:00 GMT
```

However, the following formats are supported. (Cookie was removed.)

```
Set-Cookie: expires=Wed, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

I confirmed that the former was rfc850 and the latter was rfc1123.

**I wonder if there is an official document or reference for this result.**

Answer (score 0):

You could check from the MDN docs that the detailed format is:

```
Date: <day-name>, <day> <month> <year> <hour>:<minute>:<second> GMT
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

> Expires= Optional
>   The maximum lifetime of the cookie as an HTTP-date timestamp. See Date for the detailed format. If not specified, the cookie will have the lifetime of a session cookie. A session is finished when the client is shut down meaning that session cookies will get removed at that point.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date

> The Date general HTTP header contains the date and time at which the message was originated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what I'm wondering is why ie11 does not support older formats(DD-MMM-YY). The older formats are still supported by safari, edge, chrome and firefox. Can I find development notes or release notes for IE11?

Comment: Maybe you could refer to this:https://services.anu.edu.au/files/document-collection/Changing%20browser%20date%20format_0.pdf

Comment: There is no content I want to do but it is useful information. Thanks.